# Google Calendar Add Event "insert" method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-calendar-api

It's my very first time using a Google API, and I've found a total roadblock while adding a stub Event on my own Google Calendar coming from my local Rails app.

I've tried to follow [this](https://readysteadycode.com/howto-integrate-google-calendar-with-rails) walkthrough, but it has many actions I don't need. I only want to be able to **create** an event and be able to see it online on Google Calendars.

When trying to post using the exact same code of that tutorial, I get an error related to `missing keys [calendar_id]` for an unknown reason on this last spot:

`service.insert_event(params[:calendar_id], event)`

So after giving up on making that work, I tried making the actual POST action following another solution found [here](http://landonmarder.com/posts/2014/06/04/google-cal-rails/), specifically the last part,

```
@set_event = client.execute(:api_method => service.events.insert,
                    :parameters => {'calendarId' => current_user.email, 'sendNotifications' => true},
                    :body => JSON.dump(@event),
                    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

however, Rails tells me that `events` in `service.events.insert` is an undefined method.

I'm quite frustrated having spent most of the day trying to fix it. The Oath redirection and authentication works, but I have not been able to create an event. Here is my code:

```
###Controller
class Api::V2::CalendarsController < Api::V2::BaseController
 require 'signet/oauth_2/client'
 require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
 require 'googleauth'

def redirect
 client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
  client_id: Figaro.env.google_client_id,
  client_secret: Figaro.env.google_client_secret,
  authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/'
 })
 redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
end

def callback
 client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
  client_id: Figaro.env.google_client_id,
  client_secret: Figaro.env.google_client_secret,
  token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  redirect_uri: callback_url,
  code: params[:code]
})

response = client.fetch_access_token!

session[:authorization] = response

redirect_to 'http://localhost:3000'
end

def new_event

client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
  client_id: Figaro.env.google_client_id,
  client_secret: Figaro.env.google_client_secret,
  token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
})

client.update!(session[:authorization])

service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.authorization = client

today = Date.today

event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
  start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: today),
  end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: today + 1),
  summary: 'New event!'
})

begin
  event = service.insert_event('primary', event)
 rescue Google::Apis::AuthorizationError => exception
  response = client.refresh!

  session[:authorization] = session[:authorization].merge(response)

  retry
 end
end

###Route
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
 namespace :v2 do
  get '/redirect', to: 'calendars#redirect', as: 'redirect'
  get '/callback', to: 'calendars#callback', as: 'callback'
  post '/events/new', to: 'calendars#new_event', as: 'new_event'
 end
end

###View snippet
<%= form_tag api_v2_new_event_path do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add event' %>
<% end %>
```

I'd be really thankful if anybody could point me out what's actually wrong with both variants or if there's a better way to actually create and submit the event. Thank you!

UPDATE: After following @SergeyBokolov's recommendation, I updated the code. However, I now get this when trying to submit:

```
Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
 "error" : "invalid_request",
 "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
service.insert_event('primary', event)
```

You have `missing keys [calendar_id]` because `params[:calendar_id]` is blank.

Tutorial from your second link looks outdated.

Official sample for events inserting is available [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/samples/cli/lib/samples/calendar.rb#L33).

UPDATED:
Your new error is about authorization. I recommend you to use next code for authorization:

```
service.authorization = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.new(
        {'web' => {'access_token' => YOUR_TOKEN,
                   'refresh_token' => YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                   'client_id' => YOUR_GOOGLE_APP_ID,
                   'client_secret' => YOUR_GOOGLE_APP_SECRET}}
    ).to_authorization
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the last part of the code, but I'm now getting a new and somewhat odd error. Also, it would be great if Google could link that Github page on their official docs, as I never found it trying to find a solution

Comment: this gem is one of those libs that you need to look into the code to find anything. New error is authorization error, i will update answer about it

Comment: Thank you for your input! However, where do I take both the access and refresh token for the authorization? Can I just simply call the session["authorization"] variable on them?

Comment: No these tokens are required, you can get it by google oauth - for sample gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

Comment: But the omniauth gem seems to only work if your app uses Devise. My app does not use Devise. How can I link the access and refresh token from the code that is on my post? I updated it with the callback action that was set on the tutorial post. I'm sorry beforehand, I'm really new to this and I really thank you for all the help you've given me so far.

Comment: omniauth works without devise - it is enough to put settings in other place. (Rails.application.config.middleware.use instead of config/initializers/devise.rb). https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 , you can use https://github.com/google/signet for get tokens too, but omniauth is better documented and easier to google.